# GCE port forwarding loadbalancer

Tags: load-balancing, port-forwarding, google-compute-engine

Within GCE I have 2 servers load balanced serving traffic on https.

I have added another server which I only want to **allow access** to over **port 8443** over https (https://domain.com:8443).

If I try and create a global forwarding rule it **only allows** for **port 80/443 and 8080.**

I then attempted to set-up a forwarding rule and target pool for the existing load balancer but when I attempt to set-up the forwarding rule it assigns a new external IP address.

Is there a way to set the existing load-balancer to forward port 8443 to a specific server using the existing IP and domain that is pointing to it over https?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCE does allow you to create multiple load balancers using the same IP address. But there are some limitations.

The TCP and UDP load balancers require you to use an external IP address in the same region as your backends.

The HTTP and HTTPS load balancers require you to use a global IP address.

Thus you cannot combine those kinds of load balancing on the same IP address. Moreover the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) states that:

> HTTP requests can be load balanced based on port 80 or port 8080. HTTPS requests can be load balanced on port 443.

So to the best of my knowledge there is no way to configure load balancing on port 8443 of your current IP address.